# "Push against boundaries" meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, verbs, phrase-usage

What does the phrase **" to push against boundaries "** mean as in  "*it is important to be able to say ‘no’ to children when they misbehave or try to **push against these boundaries***"?

Comment: "Put" or "push"???  They are two entirely different words.

Comment: And what do you think "boundary" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pushing against boundaries" can mean:

- Seeing how close to breaking the rules you can get without receiving punishment/scolding
- Inventing outside-the-box solutions and seeing how much you can change the status quo

Answer (score 1):

**boundary** [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/boundary)

> the limits of an activity or experience

a. **push back**/extend the **boundaries** of something:

As in:

> New research pushes back the boundaries of genetic science!

Your example:

> ...or try to test the rules, the limits, the boundaries.

Comment: So do push back the boundaries and push against the boundaries mean the same thing?